# What evolutionary mechanism caused felines to develop purring?

Tags: evolution, zoology

And why can some felines roar while others meow?

Comment: I guess the first question to ask is: "Why do cats purr?". If I remember correctly it is not really clear, so I doubt an evolutionary mechanism for it is known. As for the roaring I suspect that size matters.

Comment: Also, are you looking for an ecological answer (as in why cats perform the action of purring), or a physiological/anatomical answer (as in why a cat's purr sounds like it does)?

Comment: I just think there's no purpose to purring as far as I can tell. 'meow' seems like a more valid form of communication.

Answer (score 6):

It makes sense that the ability to express your emotions improves the quality of the interaction you have with those around you. If a cat purrs those around it know it's feeling good, which can be useful information for future interaction.

I'm sure there have been cats who had a worse life because they didn't bond as well because they didn't purr, and consequently had a slightly lesser tendency to have their DNA end up in the next generation.

This argument goes for every ability to express emotions.

Comment: Indeed, so I suppose that cats use purring to communicate with one another?

Comment: I would think so yes.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purr#Reasons lists several other possible reasons for purring. I'm not a big fan of antropomorphisation of animal habits, but I guess a clear response is still elusive in this case